# Is it OK to have asymmetric house wiring?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, smart-switch

I am converting a ceiling light with two switch locations (3-way switches) to a smart switch. Instead of a traveler 3-conductor cable going to the 'extra' switch, however, the load is in the middle of two switches. See the diagram below.

The obvious way to wire this will result in asymmetric current flow over the feeds into each switch box. The feed cable in one box will see only line current and the feed in the other box will see only neutral current when the light is on.

I live in a old house and I know that in another location this is already the case. Apparently when the attic was finished they tapped into power by converting a 2-conductor Bx from carrying (neutral, switched hot) to (switched hot, and line). I don't know where that goes and how the return current routes back. So I suspect it will work fine but is there a reason not to do this?

Thanks for your time in considering this question.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Nope, this is a straight violation of NEC 300.3(B).

Related conductors must be in the same cable or conduit.

This also violates the spirit of the rule, which is to disallow imbalanced current in the cables.  In other words **you should be able to put a GFCI *anywhere*** and have it work / clamp any cable and get 0 reading (since all currents are equal/opposite/cancel each other out).

Imbalance current is a serious threat because this is AC power.  It throws a considerable magnetic field.  It's not like a refrigerator magnet. It's like a *spinning magnet*.  It will cause vibration (cracking, overheating, arcing since copper and aluminum *do not have a fatigue limit*) and eddy current heating onto anything metallic.

EMFs get a lot of bad press because "environmental illness" undiagnosable people claim it a lot.  But it's not hoodoo; animals can sense it. Causes "failure to thrive" at farms, not least if they're afraid of the water trough or feeder.

Separate from that, 2 circuits sharing 1 neutral can overload that neutral. *Neutrals don't have breakers*.

### Re-task the /3 cable to be always-hot, neutral and signal

The proper way to implement smart switches on existing /3 cables is to use common smart switch products, and re-task the /3 cables' wires to be

- Black = always-hot
- White = actual neutral
- Red = switched-hot (or datacomm if the topology works out for that)

And then, select smart switches capable of living with that. For instance many use AC powerline or wireless communication and do not need a comm wire.

### And don't use non-UL-Listed crud either

ETL and CSA are acceptable. *CE, CCC, FCC, RoHS are not*.

There is, however, plenty of hacker-tier crud made overseas that *does not* meet our safety regulations.  That stuff is impossible to buy through reputable bricks-and-mortar retail channels, such as your friendly neighborhood electrical supply house or Home Depot (including homedepot.com). As such, most people are protected from it.  Never buy AC mains equipment mail order (there's rarely any reason to) and you won't have a problem.

Unfortunately people who are into low voltage electronics have normalized the idea of buying "mail order", and the dangerous stuff intentionally sells via mail-order to circumvent the consumer safety protocols which protect bricks-and-mortar supply houses.  Just FYI.

Comment: This stuff is ETL-listed, which should be fine. But the Z51 (referenced in a comment to my answer) is really a component, not a full switch. Updating my answer...

Comment: @manassehkatz that's only true if it's installed according to labeling and instructions.  Instructions will never advise what OP proposes, because UL/ETL will never authorize intentionally violating the electrical code (except in the rare instance where the product is designed to solve a code problem, such as a load shed device).

Comment: And actually now that I look at the unit, I see where it has a separate "L" and "IN" terminal.  *Maybe* that is there to solve this exact problem?  But SMH if the instructions approved by UL/ETL don't say you can do it, you can't do it.

Comment: The relay part is actually very useful *but not for this installation*. It allows switching a load with a different power source from the power of the relay itself. But it just isn't the right tool for *this* job. And they *make* a tool for this job - an actual switch rather than a component relay.

Comment: Another case where the answering could have been much easier if the question included the specific smart device. Which seems to be a common problem, so GIGO.

Comment: Thanks @Harper-ReinstateMonica, I was worried for a moment that these devices weren't UL certified. The FIBARO Dimmer two device actually has two sense inputs so if I switch to that I can send N,L, and switched Hot over both legs and put the device in the box in the middle. And BTW, @
manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact, you can install UL-listed stuff incorrectly so that really does not take away from his point.

Answer (score 1):

Can't do that. But shouldn't need to. A smart switch should *replace* the toggle at one end, so only one sense wire is needed to monitor the other (manual) switch, and the remaining can be repurposed for neutral or hot, as needed. No new cable feed (what you show to box 2) is needed.

Should be able to put the smart switch in either box, though I think 1 would be a little more straightforward than 2.

---

Based on a comment, this is using Zooz Z51. That is a component, not a full-fledged switch, but is ETL-listed. As such, it may or may not pass inspection. But in any case, it will not, in any way I can figure out, work in this configuration without running an additional cable somewhere (and the drawing in the question shows a way that might technically work but would *not* be code legal), or replacing the 3-wire cable with a 4-wire cable.

However, if you are committed to Zooz then there is an easy solution. The [Zen71](https://www.getzooz.com/zooz-zen71-on-off-switch/) is designed as a drop-in solution for the entire switch, not a behind the scenes component. The manual includes some sample wiring diagrams, and I think "3-way, option 2" is workable. That places the smart switch in box 1 so it gets hot and neutral. The 3-wire cable takes switched hot (Load), traveler and neutral. The light in the middle gets switched hot and neutral. Neutral and traveler continue on to the existing switch 2. In a typical (not smart) switch installation you would *never* pair neutral and traveler, but that's presumably OK here because it carries only a tiny signal current and not the full lighting load.

Comment: this is a device that goes behind the old toggle switches instead of replacing them so that the look and feel of the switches does not change. I am using Zooz Z51 and Z52s mostly and FIBARO Dimmer 2 when I need dimming. See https://www.getzooz.com/zooz-zen52-double-relay

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at the Zen51 and the ETL stuff seems to be in order, notably it has obvious instructions stating how to install the thing in home wiring. Maybe OP has a wrong or obsolete thing.

Comment: @harper, I heard from Zooz support and there is a way to make the the Zen51 work in this scenario. Its interesting. You can wire a a 3-way switch so that the two switched poles are connected to each other. Even those the steady state is the same regardless of how the switch is positioned, the S input detects the brief disconnect while the the switch changes from one pole to the other. So you can treat the 3-way as a pulse generator and wire as many as you want in series. Then you only need one wire to carry the signal instead of two in a traverler setup.

Comment: Fascinating....

Answer (score 0):

I think Meta_Alchemy ended up answering my question after all because in explaining the situation in the comment, I realized how this cant possibly be OK.

I think that a potential concern with asymmetric current is that the circuit breaker only sees the current of the 'line' (aka hot) side so if a bunch of stuff was causing current in only the 'neutral' side of a particular circuit, the breaker would not trip even though the neutral wire is carrying too much current and is heating up to the point of catching fire.

I think now that its most definitely against code because even if the circuit is over rated for today's load and handles it fine, some expecting homeowner down the line might add things to it to the point of being a problem even though the current measured at the breaker is well under the limit

Comment: Yes, that too. I forgot all about about neutral overload from 2 separate circuits.  But yes, in any case if the homeowner were to install an AFCI or GFCI, they'd instantly have problems and be forced to hunt down the violation.